# Bin Deploying MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

Hi My hosting Provider has support for MVC3 but not for MVC4. When I asked them to install MVC4 they say they support only MVC3 as the visual studio installed on the server is still in v3.5. I had read the release notes of MVC4 which requires visual studio 2010. I have converted all my application to MVC4 and having tough time with the hosting provider. My question is

1. Is there any way that I can run MVC4 application with (VS2008 and
   MVC3)
2. Can I use Bin deploy in this case? will it work?

Any suggestions are really appreciated. I dont want to downgrade my MVC4 application or dont want the hassle of transferring the hosting provider.

Comment: MVC 4 is currently a preview release. MVC 3 is the stable version and I would actually recommend downgrading to it, except... as far as I know it is not fully supported with anything less than .Net 4, either. Maybe someone else can shed some more light on that?

Comment: I would have a good look at another hosting provider if your current one a) has Visual Studio installed on their server, b) thinks Visual Studio is a dependency of deployed web applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Even MVC3 requires .NET 4.0 and VS 2010 to install the project template. If the latest .NET Framework version your host has installed on their servers is 3.5, you cannot run anything later than MVC2 over there, unfortunately.

If you drop MVC3/4 DLLs to bin, you'll get runtime errors.

Downgrade MVC, or change the host. They are due upgrading their .NET version. If they don't have that in plan soon, you're working with a dinosaur that you're likely looking at constant problems with.

Comment: I have downgraded to MVC3 and it's working now. I wonder how MVC3 works if the .net version is still 3.5.

Comment: I said that based on what I saw here: http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc3-release-notes#software-requirements; I actually didn't test that theory.

Comment: Maybe the host IS running .net 4, and there was some comm issue between you and them or within their troups? Maybe try outputting the asp.net version somewhere on your page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168279/asp-net-version-build-number