# Print Version Number in ASP.NET MVC 4 app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 application. Currently, I am setting the version of the application in the project properties under the "Application" tab. From here, I click the "Assembly Information..." button. Once there, I have entered "1 0 0 *" in the "Assembly version" field.

My question is, how do I show this value on my web page? Currently, I am trying the following

```
@System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString()
```

Unfortunately, it's always printing "0.0.0.0". Realistically, I'd like to have it print 1.0.0.xyz. I would also like to print the date/time when the last build occurred. However, I have no idea how to do that.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1168413/1374267) to see if it solves your problem...

Answer (score 127, accepted):

To print the version number of the assembly in which was defined the controller that rendered this view:

```
@ViewContext.Controller.GetType().Assembly.GetName().Version
```

and for the assembly date:

```
@File.GetCreationTime(ViewContext.Controller.GetType().Assembly.Location)
```

Comment: The assembly date is not working for me.  The assembly location is pointing to a file in the GAC which is 3 years old.  Would `File.GetLastWriteTime` work better?

Comment: How to put it in the code. I mean shall I simply paste it in the cshtml file?`<p>@ViewContext.Controller.GetType().Assembly.GetName().Version</p>`

Comment: See my comment below to get correct datetime of modification.

Answer (score 24):

I usually make `HtmlHelper` extension for this purpose. Something like this:

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString AssemblyVersion(this HtmlHelper helper)
    {
        var version = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(version);
    }
}
```

And than inside view you just call:

```
@Html.AssemblyVersion()
```

Answer (score 22):

In case you are publishing your application on a production server, I would recommend using something like

```
@String.Format(
    "{0:dddd, MMMM d, yyyy HH:mm:ss}", 
    File.GetLastWriteTime(ViewContext.Controller.GetType().Assembly.Location))
```

for retrieving the date.

This will print the actual publish date since `File.GetCreationTime()` will give you the date the actual assembly dll was **first** copied on the server.

Answer (score 5):

Working solution for correct date of modification after deploy:

```
@File.GetLastWriteTime(@System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)
```

Can be used in MVC5 too.

Answer (score 4):

This prints the current version number as outlined in your `AssemblyInfo.cs` file for printing in an ASP.NET MVC view:

```
@(typeof(MyController).Assembly.GetName().Version.ToString())
```

Replacing `MyController` of course with your appropriate MVC controller name.

Answer (score 2):

If you need this in a Razor view, this works for me.  It needed the `System.IO.*` prefix to work for me

```
<!--
Version @System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(typeof(YourNamespace.Program).Assembly.Location).ProductVersion
Last deployed on @System.IO.File.GetCreationTime(typeof(YourNamespace.Program).Assembly.Location)
-->
```

Outputs the following:

```html
<!--
Version 1.0.0
Last deployed on 04/19/2019 1:36:24 PM
-->
```

Answer (score 1):

Your assembly version may be set using the `AssemblyFileVersionAttribute`, which must be accessed specifically.

```
AssemblyFileVersionAttribute attr = typeof(MyController).Assembly.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AssemblyFileVersionAttribute), true).OfType<AssemblyFileVersionAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();

if (attr != null)
{
    return attr.Version;
}
```

The [MvcDiagnostics Nuget package](http://nuget.org/packages/MvcDiagnostics) makes this simple.

Answer (score 0):

For an ASP.NET Master Page display w/ VB.NET ...

Declaration in Master.aspx.vb

```
Public myAssembly As System.Reflection.Assemply
```

Define assembly in the Page_Load Sub of Master.aspx.vb

```
myAssembly = System.Relection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly
```

Display on the .Master page

```
<p>Version: <%Response.Write(myAssembly.GetName().Version.ToString())%></p>
```