# How to get the build time in .NET?

Tags: .net, datetime, build

Is it possible for a .NET assembly to know when it was built?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/324245/asp-net-show-application-build-date-info-at-the-bottom-of-the-screen

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an interesting article, which explains three ways to find the build date of an assembly :

[Determining Build Date the hard way](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/determining-build-date-the-hard-way.html)

Answer (score 2):

Assembly metadata does not contain a build date. You could do a couple of things though:

1. Use the filesystem's modified date to check when it was built.
2. Encode the date into the assembly version.

Answer (score 1):

If you use http://autobuildversion.codeplex.com/

It has an option to add a number of date combinations to any of the Assembly(File) Version. And it will update this on every build.

I usually have something like year + day of year as my revision numbers.

Like 1 Jan 2011 would be : 11001