# Display build date in razor file (Blazor)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I have a simple Blazor WASM app. I would like to show build date (and time) to users for debugging purposes. Just string in left down corner of the footer...

Obviously I would like to do this automatically.
Where, when and how to store the datetime to be displayed in razor file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For debugging purposes, you could use the AssemblyTitle (or any other attribute you like)

First you add it to your csproj file

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <AssemblyTitle Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'debug'">My Assembly $([System.DateTime]::Now)</AssemblyTitle>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Then in your Blazor code (MainLayout seems a good choice) you can extract the value and display it:

```html
<div class="info-panel">@BuildInfo</div>
```

```cs
@code {
  string BuildInfo;
#if DEBUG
  protected override void OnInitialized()
  {
    Assembly curAssembly = typeof(Program).Assembly;
    BuildInfo = $"{curAssembly.GetCustomAttributes(false).OfType<AssemblyTitleAttribute>().FirstOrDefault().Title}";
  }
#endif
}
```

If you don't like the idea of using an existing attribute, you could create a custom attribute - but that seems over the top to me.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why not to use this in production with release configuration?

Comment: Nope, just showing how to do it just for debug

Comment: Also needs `@using System.Reflection`

Answer (score 2):

You may find useful information in answers to the below question.

[ASP.NET - show application build date/info at the bottom of the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324245/asp-net-show-application-build-date-info-at-the-bottom-of-the-screen)

Comment: I do not care much about getting the date. I just don't know how to create something (string with date) during build time and this something present in blazor app.. It is probably very simple, I am just missing correct terms I guess..